# Magic Mouse causing Mouse Preference Pane to crash?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, magic-mouse, system-preferences

But I have a Belkin Bluetooth dongle, the one that's listed on the Apple website. It worked right out the box on my SL 10.6.7 and my magic mouse connected great.

The only problem is when going to Mouse preferences, it immediately crashes the System Preferences.

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're probably on an AMD based hackintosh booting with the -force64 flag, am I right? This means you're running the 64bit version of system preferences. The 'magic mouse prefpane' loads instructional videos by using quicktime, in this case the 64bit quicktime, which you can't use since AMD processors don't support the SSSE3 instructions (SSSE3 yes, not SSE3, big difference ;-) ). To avoid the crashing, load the 32bit version of system preferences by selecting the open in 32bit mode checkbox in the get info dialog.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wish you were right but I'm not loading the -force64 flag, its booting with arch=i386 busratio=18

Comment: Hmm, in that case I wouldn't know how to fix the crashing. Maybe you can configure your mouse another way? For example by using magic prefs (http://magicprefs.com/) or more 'hardcore' by editing preference files? (an educated guess points at /Users/<username>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse for the magic mouse).

Comment: Or my second option, go back to a PS/2 Mouse and sell the not so ergonomic magic mouse :) Thanks anyway